# How to change color of caret when drop down button is hovered

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a button(anchor tag) like this:

```
<a href ng-if="!isLogin" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<b class="white-link">Login</b> 
<span class="caret white-link"></span></a>
```

I am using `white-link` custom css class to apply color to login button.

When I hover on the login button, the css class is applied to only button but I want to apply it on both button and caret and same should work when I hover on caret. How do I do it in angular?

Comment: 1) You're going to want to do it with CSS, not JavaScript. 2) `<b>` is deprecated. Use `<strong>` instead. 3) Why is `.white-link` not on the `a` element instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with javascript nor angular
Just define your css class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
   .white-link:hover { color: red !important}
</style>

<a href  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
  <span class="white-link">
<b>Login</b> 
<span class="caret"></span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngMouseover`, `ngMouseleave` and `ngClass` directive to apply css on hover and remove it on mouseleave.

```
<button ng-class="{'white-link': login}" ng-mouseover="login = true" ng-mouseleave="login = false">Login</button>
<span ng-class="{'white-link': login}" ng-mouseover="login = true" ng-mouseleave="login = false">Text</span>
```

On hover to login button and span element, `white-link` class will be applied on both button and span.

See this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xLZ483CjBIvPz0QD7nT?p=preview).